# hyperv: How to get the controller number from WMI query?

Tags: wmi, hyper-v

When we create the SCSI hard disk for a VM, is there a way to get the scsi controller index/number. 
I understand that we can create 4 virtual SCSI controller. How do i get SCSI 0, SCSI 1, SCSI 2, SCSI 3 ?

2. The select query output of Msvm_StorageAllocationSettingData gives the instanceID. How to read this field "Microsoft:E84A07DF-EDA6-4996-A190-3E5FD724194D\5177DAB1-6F95-4618-AC73-85B66F37B4A8\0\0\L" ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

InstanceID is the instance of the Object in Msvm_StorageAllocationSettingData class. You probably require Parent attribute to get the HardDiskDrive and again you will need Parent attribute of that object to get the Controller.

In Powershell:

```
$VM = gwmi -namespace root\virtualization\v2 -query "SELECT * FROM msvm_computersystem WHERE ElementName = 'vm-name'"
$VSSD = $VM.getRelated("msvm_virtualsystemsettingdata")
$DISKS = $VSSD.getRelated("Msvm_StorageAllocationSettingData")
ForEach( $disk in DISKS ) {
    $HDD = [wmi]$disk.Parent
    $CTRL = [wmi]$hdd.Parent
    echo $CTRL
}
```

However the more important question is how to find out number of the SCSI Controller when there are more than one ? Anyone know ?

It's easy for the IDE Controllers as it's implicitly specified on the IDE Controller object, but not on SCSI Controller.